# FastAPI Jinja2Templates - Error while running initialising templates?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jinja2, fastapi, pydantic

I'm working on a simple FastAPI project and I want to use Jinja2Templates for html responses but I get error below:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from db import SessionLocal, engine
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

import models

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def home(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

I get:

```
File "C:\Users\11111\Documents\Stranky\psani web FastAPI 2\psani web FastAPI 2\.\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
  File "C:\Users\11111\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\starlette\templating.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.env = self.get_env(directory)
  File "C:\Users\11111\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\starlette\templating.py", line 56, in get_env
    @jinja2.contextfunction
AttributeError: module 'jinja2' has no attribute 'contextfunction'
```

What should i do?

pip freeze output:

```
anyio==3.6.1
fastapi==0.78.0
greenlet==1.1.2
idna==3.3
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
pydantic==1.9.1
sniffio==1.2.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.36
starlette==0.19.1
typing_extensions==4.2.0
```

Comment: I think you are using `jinja2==3.1.0` while your `starlette` version is incompatible with it.

Check the release notes: https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/1b714c7e82c73575d1dba48f560db07fe9a5cb74/CHANGES.rst#:~:text=contextfilter%20and%20contextfunction%20are%20replaced%20by%20pass_context.%20evalcontextfilter%20and%20evalcontextfunction%20are%20replaced%20by%20pass_eval_context.%20environmentfilter%20and%20environmentfunction%20are%20replaced%20by%20pass_environment.

Comment: Sorry but how do i fix it?

Comment: You should update starletter (and probably fastapi as well):
`pip install -U starlette`

Comment: I've got Jinja2==3.1.2, starlette==0.19.1, fastapi==0.78.0. It told me that it uninstalled newer starlette version because its uncompatible with fastapi so i thought it will work. It doesnt.

Comment: You might want to downgrade to `jinja2==3.0.3` because it worked for me, but I'm not sure whether I can reproduce the problem. If the problem persists, could you add the output of `pip freeze` to the question?

Comment: There you go... I tried downgrading. Didnt solve the problem

Comment: The line `@jinja2.contextfunction` was removed from Starlette over 12 months ago (and is not present in 0.19.0+ as it has been replaced with a conditional definition named `@pass_context`), so the version you're using doesn't seem like it matches the version numbers you've included. Are you sure you're actually running your code in the same environment that `pip` references?

Comment: I think so. Im sorry if I dont understand it enough.

Comment: I found this: [https://github.com/Coldcard/ckbunker/pull/19/files](https://github.com/Coldcard/ckbunker/pull/19/files) That solved my problem. Thanks for your time anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Your *fastapi* version requires a certain version of *starlette*, you need to fulfill that.

**How to solve ?**

Run command:

> pip install -r requirements.txt

Now in your terminal, you will have this kind of warning in red color

> fastapi 0.78.0 has requirement starlette==0.19.1, but you'll have
> starlette 0.20.4 which is incompatible.

Now in your *requirements.txt* file update the required *starlette* version and again run

> pip install -r requirements.txt

Hope this will solve your problem.

Note:
Go to https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/ and find the latest version of *fastapi*, use it in your *requirements.txt* then follow the above steps.